# Calendar Constructor Java toString

Tags: java, constructor, calendar

What I'm trying to do is pass a date into the Calendar so that it will format the date ready for use with another constructor. So that i can make use of it later using the functions that calendar has provides.

```
public class Top {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Something st = new Something(getCalendar(20,10,2012));       
    System.out.println(st.toString());       
    }

public static Calendar getCalendar(int day, int month, int year){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    return cal;
    }
}
```

The tostring method.

```
public String toString(){
    String s = "nDate: " + DateD;
    return s;
}
```

Date: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true

Rather than
Date: 20/10/2012

Comment: FYI, the `java.util.Calendar` is one of the old date-time classes that have proven to be troublesome, confusing, and flawed. Now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `DateD` is `Calendar` , it is default `toString()` implementation. You need to call `getTime()` to get the `date` out of it.

From the java doc of [Calendar#toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#toString%28%29)

> Return a string representation of this calendar. This method is intended to be used only for debugging purposes, and the format of the returned string may vary between implementations. The returned string may be empty but may not be null.

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert it to `String`

Comment: Thank you this was the solution i was looking for. I'd vote it up but this is my first ever question here.

Answer (score 1):

First you don't need to use `toString()` method explicitly while printing your instances. It will be called automatically.

Also, you should use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format your `Date` to required string format: -

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String date = format.format(cal.getTime());

System.out.println(date);
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
2012/10/20
```

Comment: @Downvoter. Ok, I've improved my post. I think you can now remove the downvote.

Comment: Hi Rohit, I don't care for the string concatenation solution, but that's a personal choice.  I'll reverse.

Comment: @duffymo. Yeah thanks :). I know I did it wrong first time.. `DateFormat` should be the first choice to format date.

Comment: @duffymo. I like your way though. That is far too handy when it comes too lot of conversion :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the date represented by a calendar instance, as a string, you should use [`SimpleDateFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format the date in the required format, as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(DateD.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like too much work to me.

As a user, I'd rather pass a Date and make the contract clear.  Provide a convenience method that converts String to Date:

```
public class Top {

    public static final DateFormat DEFAULT_FORMAT;

    static {
        DEFAULT_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
        DEFAULT_FORMAT.setLenient(false);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
    }

    public static Date convert(String dateStr) throws ParseException {
        return DEFAULT_FORMAT.parse(dateStr);
    }     

    public static String convert(Date d) {
        return DEFAULT_FORMAT.format(d);
    }   
}
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is not threadsafe, and should not be stored as a static field. You need to create a local SimpleDateFormat as needed, or look at threadsafe alternatives (Apache commons lang has FastDateFormat), pooling, or using ThreadLocal.

Answer (score 0):

## `LocalDate`

Apparently you want a date-only value without a day-of-time. For that use the `LocalDate` class rather than `Calendar`. The `Calendar` class was for a date plus a time-of-day. Furthermore, `Calendar` is now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes after having proven to be troublesome, confusing, and flawed.

Simply pass the desired year, month, and day-of-month to a factory method. The month is sanely numbered 1-12 for January-December unlike `Calendar`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2012 , 10 , 20 );
```

Or, pass a constant for month.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2012 , Month.OCTOBER , 20 );
```

The java.time classes tend to use static factory methods rather than constructors with `new`.

## Strings

To generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format, call `toString`

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

> 2012-10-20

For other formats, search Stack Overflow for `DateTimeFormatter`. For example:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" );
String output = ld.format( f );
```

> 20/10/2012